# Why does Eclipse builds source in non-source folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I have just set up a new Eclipse Java project. In this project I included a folder called `external`, holding things like jars, and the source of these jars. The **only** source folder in the project is the empty `src/` folder, neither the `external/` folder nor any subdirectories of the `external/` folder are marked as source folders.

Nonetheless Eclipse chooses to compile (and choke on) the source files located beneath the `external/` folder. Does anybody know why it would do that, and how to stop it from attempting to compile these files?

**Update**

The file hierarchy is:

```
project/
    src/ (Marked as source folder)
    bin/
    external/ (Linked folder, not marked as source folder)
```

The `external/` folder is created by right-clicking on the project, choosing New -> Folder, clicking advanced and choosing "Link to alternate location". And then I have provided a relative path to a folder outside of my source hierarchy.

I have this `external/` folder configured in several other projects exactly like this, without any problems.

**Solution**

The code was not compiled at all, Eclipse had marked warnings and errors in the source files in the `external/` directory, and therefore I assumed Eclipse tried to compile these sources. However, the warnings/errors were added by my checkstyle plugin in Eclipse. Which by default parses source files in all directories in projects for which it is enabled.

Thus the solution is to instruct checkstyle only to analyse sources in folders that are marked at source folders.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: try closing and reopening the project/eclipse and check if your statements about the source folders still hold

Comment: @Jens: Tried that, also tried to close and repoen eclipse. There is still only the empty src/ folder marked as the source folder. However a build still attempts to build the source in the external/ folder. :/

Comment: just to be sure, is `external` a subdirectory of `src`?

Comment: @Carlos: It is not. :) I have updated the question with some clarification.

Comment: Idea1: Do you have any other build tools around that might get triggered by eclipse?

Comment: Idea2: Search the files in the .setting folder of you project for the name of the directory. That might give you some idea, where this is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle which folders contain code for Eclipse to compile by right clicking on the folder, highlighting Build Path, then selecting "Use as Source Folder" or "Remove from Build Path". Any folder you remove from the Build Path will just show any .java source as a text file.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, only the `src/` folder is a source folder (looking in the Java Build Path dialog). `external/` is not a source folder, however it still attempts to build sources in it.

Comment: Do you have the folder added as a class folder in the Libraries tab of the Java Build Path? Or perhaps the path is included in the Classpath Variables for your workspace?

Comment: I have a jar in the `external/` folder added in the Libraries tab, besides that I have the system JRE, and that is all. I have no idea why it would be part of my workspace classpath, but I don't know how to check for that either?

Comment: If you go to Window > Preferences then expand Java and click Build Path, you can see all of the workspace-level settings for build.

How have you added the JAR file to your project?

Comment: The folder is not included that way either. Only things like ECLIPSE_HOME, JRE_*, FINDBUGS*, JUNIT*. :/

Comment: Just noticed your edit about it being a Linked Folder - if you right click on it and select Properties, and click the "Edit..." button then "Variable...", are there any path variables beyond the four defaults?

Comment: Yes, there is a fifth one that I added at some point, but it should not be relevant. It points to somewhere entirely different on my file-system. The link simply points to: "PROJECT_LOC/../external" if that is of any help.

Comment: When you expand the linked folder, do the file icons for the .java files that are being compiled have a blue 'J' or a white 'J'?

Comment: I just realised what is going on. They are not being compiled at all, they are being processed by checkstyle, which generates both errors and warnings. Making me think they are being compiled. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Eclipse's file system is not synchronized with your actual file system. To let Eclipse know that a folder exists in your project directory you have to click and drag it into your projects view in Eclipse.

Comment: I thought just refreshing (F5) the folder in eclipse was enough, however this is not my problem.